# Regular Expression - Starts With Value or After Second Comma Starts With Value

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to develop a regular expression that has this logic:

```
if(startsWith(value) || afterSecondCommaStartsWith(value)) {}
```

I have a string like:

`Thomas Municipal Court, Creber, Lester County, TX 12345`

If `value = "Tho"` or `value = "Les"` it should match

I'm implementing this in JavaScript and this is what I have so far:

```
var matcher = new RegExp("^", $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
```

This works for `value = "Tho"`, but not `value = "Les"` (because I don't have the comma logic).

(Also,  I'm using this for JQuery UI Autocomplete logic if anyone cares)

Answer (score 1):

You can build a dynamic regex.

```js
let value1 = "Tho"
let value2 = "Les"
let str = `Thomas Municipal Court, Thomas, Lester County, TX 79457`

let reg = `(?:^${value1})|(?:^.*?,.*?,\\s*${value2})`

var matcher = new RegExp(reg,"i");
console.log(matcher)
console.log(matcher.test(str))
```

Comment: It returns `false` for `value2`

Comment: @KolobCanyon just add one more '\' before `s`